# How to implement Multiple Table Inheritance in Rails: foreign keys or type + id?

Tags: database, postgresql, activerecord

I want to introduce a new "parent" concept in my Rails application's model.

I already have `taskA` and `taskB` tables that are holding data about tasks of different types. `taskA` and `taskB` have a lot of differences but some common properties. I now want to introduce another model, `taskParent` that will hold a copy of the common data for faster lookups and have a reference to either `taskA` or `taskB`. `taskParent` will have its own table. At this point in time my app will only read data from `taskParent` while all the writes will be performed on the child tables.

From `taskParent` table, how can I reference `taskA` or `taskB`? It seems like I have two options:

**A)** One `type` and one `id` column.

**Pro**: easy to support new task types if I will introduce other tables for different types of tasks in the future

**Cons**: difficult to maintain referential integrity since it cannot be implemented at the database level with foreign keys (as far as I know)

**B)** One column for every child table with a foreign key constraint and a db constraint that ensure only one foreign key is set

**Pro**: easier to ensure referential integrity. Could automatically delete an item from `taskParent` if related `taskA` or `taskB` is deleted.

**Cons**: difficult to support other types of tasks as this would require adding additional columns to the table and modify the DB constraint that ensures uniqueness

I would really like to have constraints at the DB level but the cons of the B approach scare me as it is very possible I will add other types of tasks (and their respective table) in the future. Does anybody have any suggestions on which approach to take?

I am using Postgres.

Comment: c) There is built-in inheritance in PostgreSQL, but I doubt that activerecord will work well with it: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński thanks I didn't know about that! As you mentioned, that does not sound a good option for me since I would want to interact with the db mostly with active record.